# Distribution of sum of a discrete uniform and a uniform on (0,2)

Tags: self-study, cumulative-distribution-function

> Let $U$ be uniformly distributed on the interval $(0, 2)$ and let $V$ be an independent
> random variable which has a discrete uniform distribution on ${0, 1, . . . , n}$. i.e. $P\{V = i\} =\frac{1}{n + 1}$ for $i = 0, 1, . . . , n.$ Find the cumulative distribution function of $X = U + V$.

I did the following, how do I calculate the minimum?
$P(X \leq x)=P(U+V<x)=\sum_{v=0}^nP(U<v-x|V=v)P(V=v)=\sum_{v=0}^nP(U<v-x)P(V=v)=\sum_{v=0}^n \big[\int_0^{\min(x-v,2)} \frac{1}{2}du\big]P(V=v)=\sum_{v=0}^n\frac{\min(x-v,2)}{2(n+1)}$

Comment: You might find it easier to do this in parts: below $0$, between $0$ and $1$, between $1$ and $2$, between $2$ and $n$, between $n$ and $n+1$, between $n+1$ and $n+2$, above $n+2$.

Comment: **You don't need any calculations.** Write $U$ as an equal mixture of a Uniform$(0,1)$ and Uniform$(1,2)$ variables.  Notice that when you add the first component to $V$ you obtain a uniform $(0,n+1)$ variable.  Because the second component has the same distribution as the first shifted by $+1,$ the sum of the second component and $V$ has a uniform $(1,n+2)$ distribution.  Therefore the answer is the equal mixture of those two distributions.  You can *immediately* sketch a graph of its CDF by geometrically averaging those two Uniform CDFs (which are each locally linear).

Comment: @whuber thanks! Found it very intuitive and easy.

Answer (score 2):

The hint in comments notes that you might find it easier to break things down by looking at the distribution over each unit interval.  To do this formally, we can use the alternative decomposition:

$$X = U_* + R + V
\quad \quad \quad 
U_* \sim \text{U}(0,1)
\quad \quad \quad 
R \sim \text{U} \{ 0,1 \}
\quad \quad \quad 
V \sim \text{U} \{ 0,n \}.$$

(This decomposition breaks things up so that $U = R + U_*$ so that we are dealing with three random variables all with support within the unit interval.)  To facilitate analysis, let us define the following notation (which is an extension of the idea of [Macaulay brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaulay_brackets)):

$$\{ u|a \} 
\equiv \max(0, \min(u, a))
= \begin{cases}
0 & & & \text{if } u < 0, \\[6pt]
u & & & \text{if } 0 \leqslant u \leqslant a, \\[6pt]
a & & & \text{if } u > a. \\[6pt]
\end{cases}$$

We will make use the CDF of the uniform random variable $U_*$ over the unit interval, which can be written as $F(u) \equiv \mathbb{P}(U_* \leqslant u) = \{ u|1 \}$.  Using the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probabilityhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), we have:

$$\begin{align}
F_X(x) 
&\equiv \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant x) \\[18pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(R+U_*+V \leqslant x) \\[12pt]
&= \sum_{r=0}^1 \sum_{v=0}^n \mathbb{P}(R+U_*+V \leqslant x | R=r, V=v) \cdot \mathbb{P}(R=r) \cdot \mathbb{P}(V=v) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2(n+1)} \sum_{r=0}^1 \sum_{v=0}^n \mathbb{P}(R+U_*+V \leqslant x | R=r, V=v) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2(n+1)} \bigg[ \quad \sum_{v=0}^n \mathbb{P}(R+U_*+V \leqslant x | R=0, V=v) \\[6pt]
&\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad + \sum_{v=0}^n \mathbb{P}(R+U_*+V \leqslant x | R=1, V=v) \bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2(n+1)} \bigg[ \sum_{v=0}^n \mathbb{P}(U_* \leqslant x-v) + \sum_{v=0}^n \mathbb{P}(U_* \leqslant x-v-1) \bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2(n+1)} \bigg[ \sum_{v=0}^n \mathbb{P}(U_* \leqslant x-v) + \sum_{v=1}^{n+1} \mathbb{P}(U_* \leqslant x-v) \bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2(n+1)} \bigg[ \sum_{v=0}^{n+1} \mathbb{P}(U_* \leqslant x-v) + \sum_{v=1}^n \mathbb{P}(U_* \leqslant x-v) \bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2(n+1)} \bigg[ \sum_{v=0}^{n+1} \{ x-v|1 \} + \sum_{v=1}^n \{ x-v|1 \} \bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2(n+1)} \bigg[ \sum_{v=0}^{n+1} \{ x-v|1 \} + \sum_{v=0}^{n-1} \{ (x-1)-v|1 \} \bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2(n+1)} \bigg[ \{ x|n+2 \} + \{ x-1|n \} \bigg]. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Thus we can write the CDF of $X$ in a simple succinct form as:

$$\begin{align}
F_X(x) 
&= \frac{\{ x|n+2 \} + \{ x-1|n \}}{2n+2}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

(See if you can understand the penultimate step in this working, where we sum a set of terms using extended Macaulay brackets into a single term using extended Macaulay brackets.)

Comment: +1 This is a great solution, but the working out as shown might be the most opaque possible way to derive and express the answer!  One picture will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks whuber.  I tend to think that this method would augment the picture, since it uses extended Macauley terms that would essentially correspond to the unit-pieces that would form such a picture.  In any case, thanks for the compliment.